# Change video on link hover

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am trying to make this effect ( https://www.stornerprod.com/directors ) that change the video on link hover.

I went with GSAP, it should do the deal, but even though it changes the video URL, when I hover my link, the video itself does not refresh, what am I missing?

Thanks for any help provided!

HTML

```
     <video id="videoBG"  autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="./wp-content/uploads/2021/08/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

 </video><div class="menu-home is-flex is-flex-column">
                       <div class="menu-home ">
                         <a data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/test.mp4" href="/commercial/">
            test</a>
                      </div>
```

my Gsap

```
$('.menu-home a').hover(function () {
   var value = $(this).attr('data-src');
   TweenMax.to('#videoBG source', 2, { attr: { src: value }, ease: Power1.easeOut, });
});
```

Comment: I don't see how you could Tween a source change for a video. Its either the old one or it isn't.

Comment: Deckerz is correct. But also note that you're using the really old syntax for GSAP. If you use GSAP, use GSAP 3: https://greensock.com/get-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");

var links=  document.querySelectorAll("a.link")
links.forEach(a=>{
    a.addEventListener("mousemove",()=>{
    if(a.matches(':hover')){
        if(video.src != a.getAttribute("link")){
            video.src=a.getAttribute("link");
        }
        
    }
    })
})
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=>{

});
```

```css
#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row
}
#video,.link{
    margin: 10px;
}
.link{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: silver;

    padding: 10px;
        width: calc(100% + 100px)
}
#link-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">


<video id="video" autoplay src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" width="350"></video>
    <div id="link-container">
        <a href="#" class="link" link="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">video no.1</a>
        <a href="#" class="link" link="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm">video no.2</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

I made a code in which you can add `<a>` elements with an attribute `link` in which you can change the link of the video.

Hover over `video no.1` and `video no.2` to change the video

The videos are taken from w3schools and MDN

Comment: you sir made my day :)

Answer (score -1):

to change color of the text when you hover over it write this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Answer</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link, a:visited{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:black;
            background-color:none;

        }
        a:hover,a:active{
            text-decoration: none;
            color:red;
            background-color:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```